# PHP - Вывод по категориям в цикле

Tags: php, mysql

Вывожу из БД, логика примерно такая:

```
$STH = $DBH->query('SELECT id,name,image,link,categ from products');  
$STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);  

  while($row = $STH->fetch()) {  

    $content='<a href="product.php?link='.$row['link'].'"><div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 col-sm-6 mainposter">'.
    '<div class="wrapp_mainposter_content">'.
    '<img src="img_tovar/'.$row['image'].'" class="mainblockimg"/>'.
    '<div class="mainposter_title">'.$row['name'].'</div>'.
    '</div></div></a>';

    if($row['categ']=='categ1'){ echo "<h2>Категория1</h2>".$content}
    if($row['categ']=='categ2'){ echo "<h2>Категория2</h2>".$content}
  }
```

Хочу вывести заголовок + товары, но разумеется так, как в цикле, заголовок выводится кучу раз, это можно, конечно, решить с помощью 2-ух отдельных запросов с `where`, но это как то не оптимально.

Comment: Вы сделали практически все, что бы на ваш вопрос было невозможно ответить. во первых `*` в запросе, вместо перечисления тех полей которые действительно нужны значительно усложняет понимание структуры таблицы (которую вы не привели). во вторых вы не написали когда собственно заголовок выводить, а когда нет. И сортировка идет по id, я так подозреваю, что из за этого товары будут выводится то из одной, то из другой категории, а тогда заголовки будут всегда нужны потому что одна и та же категория может встречаться много раз в разных местах

Comment: вообще было бы логично, если бы шла сортировка по категории, content выводился всегда, а заголовок выводился только в том случае если у предыдущей строки заголовок был другой (надо просто запоминать последнее значение заголовка после вывода и на следующем цикле вы сможете его сравнить)

Comment: Не размещайте код html в php переменных. Дурная практика, которая мешает абсолютно всему: восприятию, логике, поддержке кода.

Comment: @DaemonHK. а как лучше это делать?

Comment: @zkolya как минимум закрывая php теги и выводя html как есть, расставляя php переменные, где нужно через <?php echo $var; ?> или <?=$var?> (как хостинг позволяет), как максимум использовать шаблонизаторы (но это на большого любителя).

Comment: @DaemonHK скорее шаблонизаторы это нормальный подход, а вот вся прочая генерация html на чистом пхп это на любителей поговнокодить

Comment: @DaemonHK, может ,конечно,ошибаюсь,но как иначе это сделать ,тут ведь цикл, так то по сути я понял ,что Вы имеете в виду,один раз инициализировали,присвоили и расставлять внутри html

Answer (score 0):

Самое тупое решение "в лоб":

```
<?php
$STH = $DBH->query('SELECT id,name,image,link,categ from products');
$STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$result = $STH->fetchAll();
?>
    <h2>Категория 1</h2>
<?php
foreach($result as $row) {
    if($row['categ']=='categ1'){
?>
        <a href="product.php?link=<?=$row['link']?>">
            <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 col-sm-6 mainposter">
                <div class="wrapp_mainposter_content">
                    <img src="img_tovar/<?=$row['image']?>" class="mainblockimg"/>
                    <div class="mainposter_title"><?=$row['name']?></div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </a>
<?php
    }
}
?>
    <h2>Категория 2</h2>
<?php
foreach($result as $row) {
    if($row['categ']=='categ2'){
        ?>
        <a href="product.php?link=<?=$row['link']?>">
            <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 col-sm-6 mainposter">
                <div class="wrapp_mainposter_content">
                    <img src="img_tovar/<?=$row['image']?>" class="mainblockimg"/>
                    <div class="mainposter_title"><?=$row['name']?></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
        <?php
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Как всегда, основную мысль уже обозначили в комментариях.

Идея: при прохождении в цикле сначала распихиваем в массивчик по категориям, а затем уже по этому (результирующему) массивчику выводим.

Единственное что скажу, раз Вы всё равно используете величайшее изобретение человечества (PDO), то почему бы не использовать и FETCH_GROUP:

```
$STH = $DBH->query('SELECT categ,id,name,image,link from products');
$data = $STH->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP | PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach($data as $categ => $c_data) {
    if($categ =='categ1'){ echo "<h2>Категория1</h2>"}
    if($categ =='categ2'){ echo "<h2>Категория2</h2>"}
    foreach($c_data as $row) {
        echo '<a href="product.php?link='.$row['link'].'">'.
            '<div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 col-sm-6 mainposter">'.
            '<div class="wrapp_mainposter_content">'.
            '<img src="img_tovar/'.$row['image'].'" class="mainblockimg"/>'.
            '<div class="mainposter_title">'.$row['name'].'</div>'.
            '</div></div></a>';
    }
}
```

Остальное, про что пишут в комментах - это на любителя. Если проект еще на стадии зародыша - имеет смысл действительно подумать о шаблонизаторах, фреймворках и прочем, потому что "прикрутить потом" будет намного сложнее, чем сделать это сразу. Но это решать Вам.

Использовавшаяся для решения задачи информация:

[ссылка1](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.fetch.php)

[ссылка2](http://phpfaq.ru/pdo/fetch)